# How to fetch all images from custom Photo Album - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, photo, phasset

How to fetch *all images* from *custom* Photo Album?

```
var fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate", ascending: false)]
fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.Image.rawValue)
let allImages:PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchKeyAssetsInAssetCollection(albumList[index].collection, options: fetchOptions)
```

This code block is fetching just a few of them.
Thanks.

-> `albumList[index].collection` 's type is `PHAssetCollection`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For Swift 4

using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28904792/4795651 edited a little for myself.

```
import Photos


func fetchCustomAlbumPhotos()
{
    let albumName = "Album Name Here"
    var assetCollection = PHAssetCollection()
    var albumFound = Bool()
    var photoAssets = PHFetchResult<AnyObject>()
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()

    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
    let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

    if let firstObject = collection.firstObject{
        //found the album
        assetCollection = firstObject
        albumFound = true
    }
    else { albumFound = false }
    _ = collection.count
    photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: nil) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>
    let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()
    photoAssets.enumerateObjects{(object: AnyObject!,
        count: Int,
        stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

        if object is PHAsset{
            let asset = object as! PHAsset
            print("Inside  If object is PHAsset, This is number 1")

            let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth,
                                   height: asset.pixelHeight)

            /* For faster performance, and maybe degraded image */
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
            options.isSynchronous = true

            imageManager.requestImage(for: asset,
                                              targetSize: imageSize,
                                              contentMode: .aspectFill,
                                              options: options,
                                              resultHandler: {
                                                (image, info) -> Void in
                                                self.photo = image!
                                                /* The image is now available to us */
                                                self.addImgToArray(uploadImage: self.photo!)
                                                print("enum for image, This is number 2")

            })

        }
    }
}

func addImgToArray(uploadImage:UIImage)
{
    self.images.append(uploadImage)

}
```

For Swift 2.1

```
import Photos


func FetchCustomAlbumPhotos()
{
    var albumName = "SwiftAlbum"
    var assetCollection = PHAssetCollection()
    var albumFound = Bool()
    var photoAssets = PHFetchResult()

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
    let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Album, subtype: .Any, options: fetchOptions)

    if let first_Obj:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{
        //found the album
        assetCollection = collection.firstObject as! PHAssetCollection
        albumFound = true
    }
    else { albumFound = false }
    var i = collection.count
    photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssetsInAssetCollection(assetCollection, options: nil)
    let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()

    //        let imageManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()

    photoAssets.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock{(object: AnyObject!,
        count: Int,
        stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

        if object is PHAsset{
            let asset = object as! PHAsset
            print("Inside  If object is PHAsset, This is number 1")

            let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth,
                height: asset.pixelHeight)

            /* For faster performance, and maybe degraded image */
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = .FastFormat
            options.synchronous = true

            imageManager.requestImageForAsset(asset,
                targetSize: imageSize,
                contentMode: .AspectFill,
                options: options,
                resultHandler: {
                    (image, info) -> Void in
                    self.photo = image!
                    /* The image is now available to us */
                    self.addImgToArray(self.photo)
                    print("enum for image, This is number 2")

            })

        }
    }
}

func addImgToArray(uploadImage:UIImage)
{
    self.images.append(uploadImage)

}
```

Comment: I am wondering if the opposite is also possible? So ALL photos, EXCEPT the ones from one album (e.g. WhatsApp)?

Answer (score 2):

This is a custom album, so what you've got to do is to add it to your code in the middle:

```
import Photos

class CustomPhotoAlbum {

static let albumName = "Album"
static let sharedInstance = CustomPhotoAlbum()

var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection!

init() {

    func fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() -> PHAssetCollection! {

        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", CustomPhotoAlbum.albumName)
        let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

        if let firstObject: AnyObject = collection.firstObject {
            return collection.firstObject as? PHAssetCollection
        }

        return nil
    }

    if let assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum() {
        self.assetCollection = assetCollection
        return
    }

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: CustomPhotoAlbum.albumName)
    }) { success, _ in
        if success {
            self.assetCollection = fetchAssetCollectionForAlbum()
        }
    }
}

func saveImage(image: UIImage) {

    if assetCollection == nil {
        return   // If there was an error upstream, skip the save.
    }

    PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
        let assetChangeRequest = PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
        let assetPlaceholder = assetChangeRequest.placeholderForCreatedAsset
        let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: self.assetCollection)
        albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([assetPlaceholder] as NSFastEnumeration)
    }, completionHandler: nil)
}


}
```

Then to fetch all the pics in your album use this code:

```
func getAlbum(title: String, completionHandler: @escaping (PHAssetCollection?) -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", title)
        let collections = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

        if let album = collections.firstObject {
            completionHandler(album)
        } else {
            self?.createAlbum(withTitle: title, completionHandler: { (album) in
                completionHandler(album)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

To call this function use this example:

```
getAlbum(title: "Album") { [weak self] assetCollection in 
        guard let this = self else { return }
        guard assetCollection != nil else { return }
        print(assetCollection!)
    }
```

If you want to create a custom album use this function:

```
 func createAlbum(withTitle title: String, completionHandler: @escaping (PHAssetCollection?) -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        var placeholder: PHObjectPlaceholder?

        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let createAlbumRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: title)
            placeholder = createAlbumRequest.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection
        }, completionHandler: { (created, error) in
            var album: PHAssetCollection?
            if created {
                let collectionFetchResult = placeholder.map { PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [$0.localIdentifier], options: nil) }
                album = collectionFetchResult?.firstObject
            }

            completionHandler(album)

        })
    }
}
```

This function will be called in the getAlbum, if the album isn't created.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to get Photos from a specific Album

```
func get_Photos_From_Album(albumName: String)
        {
            var photoLibraryImages = [UIImage]()
            var photoLibraryAssets = [PHAsset]()
            //whatever you need, you can use UIImage or PHAsset to photos in UICollectionView

            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async
            {
                let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.image.rawValue)

                let smartAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .any, options: nil)
                let customAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: nil)

                [smartAlbums, customAlbums].forEach {
                    $0.enumerateObjects { collection, index, stop in

                        let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

                        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
                        requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
                        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

                        let photoInAlbum = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: collection, options: fetchOptions)

                        if let title = collection.localizedTitle
                        {
                            if photoInAlbum.count > 0
                            {
                                print("\n\n \(title) --- count = \(photoInAlbum.count) \n\n")
                            }

                            if title == albumName
                            {
                                if photoInAlbum.count > 0
                                {
                                    for i in (0..<photoInAlbum.count).reversed()
                                    {
                                        imgManager.requestImage(for: photoInAlbum.object(at: i) as PHAsset , targetSize: CGSize(width: 150, height: 150), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                                            image, error in
                                            if image != nil
                                            {
                                                photoLibraryImages.append(image!)
 photoLibraryAssets.append(photoInAlbum.object(at: i))
                                            }
                                        })
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**SWIFT 4**

```
func FetchCustomAlbumPhotos()
{
    let albumName = "AlbumName"
    var assetCollection = PHAssetCollection()
    var albumFound = Bool()
    var photoAssets = PHFetchResult<AnyObject>()

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
    let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)

    if let _:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{
        //found the album
        assetCollection = collection.firstObject!
        albumFound = true
    }
    else { albumFound = false }
    _ = collection.count
    photoAssets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: assetCollection, options: nil) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>
    let imageManager = PHCachingImageManager()

    //        let imageManager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()

    photoAssets.enumerateObjects{(object: AnyObject!,
        count: Int,
        stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in

        if object is PHAsset{
            let asset = object as! PHAsset
            print("Inside  If object is PHAsset, This is number 1")

            let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth,
                                   height: asset.pixelHeight)

            /* For faster performance, and maybe degraded image */
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            options.deliveryMode = .fastFormat
            options.isSynchronous = true

            imageManager.requestImage(for: asset,
                                              targetSize: imageSize,
                                              contentMode: .aspectFit ,
                                              options: options,
                                              resultHandler: {
                                                (image, info) -> Void in
                                                print("Image \(String(describing: image))")
                                                //self.photo = image!
                                                /* The image is now available to us */
                                                //self.addImgToArray(self.photo)
                                                print("enum for image, This is number 2")

            })

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written