# How to redirect to camera roll photos from own application

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, redirect

I am working on camera app and want to open camera roll folder from my application. 
With the help of this code

```
"UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"photos-redirect://")!)"
```

i am able to open photos app from my app but i want to open specific camera roll folder folder from my app.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752437/swift-select-all-photos-from-specific-photos-album

Comment: Not a duplicate.