# PHFetchOptions include only photos from iPhone camera

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, phasset, phfetchoptions

Right now I use that to exclude Screenshots:

```
let options = PHFetchOptions()
options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (mediaSubtype & \(PHAssetMediaSubtype.photoScreenshot.rawValue) != 0)")
var fetchResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset> = fetchResult = 
PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: PHAssetMediaType.image, options: options)
```

But I want to include only photos that were taken from iPhone Camera (not photos that were saved from other applications like Skype and so on). Is it possible?

Comment: I hope this will help you, please follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169185/how-to-fetch-all-images-from-custom-photo-album-swift

Comment: @PaulMarshal , thanks I didn't know that I can filter by album name, but that doesn't solve the issue how to extract photos that I took on camera (that were not saved from other applications)

Comment: https://github.com/alexanderkent/PHAsset-Meta try filtering images with meta data

Comment: @AbhishekMaster , thanks, that was exactly what I did

Comment: @PaulT. so you fetch all photos and then filter using the metadata? I tried that, but that was very slow (I have > 30k photos)
Is there no other way to filter out certain albums?