# Swift Looping through images in the Library and sending them to the server

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

For my Thesis I should create an App that views all photos then send them to a server (IBM Watson) to be analysed. I have been able to view the photos and cache them using the [apple photo framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/UsingPhotosFramework/Introduction/Intro.html). I made few modification to the code from the example so far. Currently I am stuck in the phase of looping through all the photos and be able to send them to the server. So I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28885391/how-to-loop-through-a-photo-gallery-in-swift-with-photos-framework/28904792#28904792) stating how to fetch and send to API but I cannot modify it to implement it on the example previously. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can use the Alamofire(https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#uploading-data-to-a-server) see the section of "Uploading Multipart Form Data" on given github link.

Comment: Use the framework @RamkrishnaSharma has mentioned